# How can I make an instance persist across requests in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra

I'm using Sinatra to build a very simple 'command center' to control various USB devices.

I have created classes like `class Device` and subclassed the various types of devices.

The problem is that, I don't want to use a database to store all my information. The list of devices will never change, and I want it to be more portable by just defining them in a constants file or just in plain ruby (I will hardcode the device ID's, etc).

The problem is when the app first loads they appear, and when i refresh they disappear. I've tried putting it in various parts of the app and I can't figure out where they should go.

I've also tried putting it in a before filter, but then it creates duplicates of them for every refresh (... and oddly, when you refresh after the 6th time or so it resets them back to 1, I have no idea what that's about).

Also, depending on whether I use `rackup config.ru` or `thin -R config.ru start` it also acts quite differently...

Thanks!

**app.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'

module RhubarbPi 
  class App < Sinatra::Application
    configure do
      set     :root, App.root
      disable :method_override
    end

    helpers do
      include Rack::Utils
      alias_method :h, :escape_html
    end
  end
end

Dir.glob('./{models,lib,routes}/*.rb').each { |file| require file }
```

**lib/devices.rb** (these are instances of the devices themselves that I'm basically 'hardcoding').

```
USBSK.new(1)
USBSM.new(1)
USBWK.new(1, '192.168.1.127')
```

Here's a sample model... simple

```
class USBSK

  attr_reader :id

  def initialize(id)
    @id = id
  end

  def self.all
    ObjectSpace.each_object(self).to_a
  end

end
```

In my views I'm doing

```
<% USBSK.all.each do |dev| %>                 
  <ul>                                      
    <li><span>ID:</span> <%= dev.id %></li> 
  </ul>                                     
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't keeping any references to the objects, so Ruby is garbage-collecting them. Also, don't use `ObjectSpace` to find your items, it's mainly for debug and introspection tasks.

I would alter **lib/devices.rb** to use a Ruby constant, like this

```
   class USBSK
     ALL_DEVICES = [
       self.new(1),
       self.new(1),
       self.new(1, '192.168.1.127')
     ]
   end
```

which you will need to `require` after the constructor has been defined, obviously.

Then alter your class all-devices accessor:

```
  def self.all
    ALL_DEVICES
  end
```

Comment: Oh, that is really clever... all really good points... thanks!